# How to insert value of UUID?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, anorm

I'm using anorm 2.4 in play framework 2.3 backed postgresql 9.4

Give a model like this:

```
case class EmailQueue(id:UUID,
                  send_from:String,
                  send_to:String,
                  subject:String,
                  body:String,
                  created_date:Date,
                  is_sent:Boolean,
                   email_template:String)
```

This is my parser:

```
val parser: RowParser[EmailQueue] = {
get[UUID]("id") ~
  get[String]("send_from") ~
  get[String]("send_to") ~
  get[String]("subject") ~
  get[String]("body") ~
  get[Date]("created_date") ~
  get[Boolean]("is_sent") ~
  get[String]("email_template") map {
  case id ~ send_from ~ send_to ~ subject ~ body ~
    created_date ~ is_sent ~ email_template=> EmailQueue(id,
    send_from,
    send_to,
    subject,
    body,
    created_date,
    is_sent,
    email_template)
}
```

}

And this is my insert statement:

```
def insert(email:EmailQueue): Unit ={
DB.withTransaction { implicit c =>
  SQL(s"""
        INSERT INTO "email_queue" ( "body", "created_date", "id", "is_sent", "send_from", "send_to", "subject", "email_template")
        VALUES ( {body}, {created_date}, {id}, {is_sent}, {send_from}, {send_to}, {subject}, {email_template} );
      """).on(
      "body" -> email.body,
      "created_date" -> email.created_date,
      "id" -> email.id,
      "is_sent" -> email.is_sent,
      "send_from" -> email.send_from,
      "send_to" -> email.send_to,
      "subject" -> email.subject,
      "email_template" -> email.email_template
    ).executeInsert()
}
```

}

I receive following error when inserting:

> [error]    PSQLException: : ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but
>   expression is  of type character varying [error]   Hint: You will need
>   to rewrite or cast the expression. [error]   Position: 153 
>   (xxxxxxxxxx.java:2270)

The database table is created by this query:

```
CREATE TABLE email_queue (
   id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
   send_from VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   send_to VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   subject VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
   body text NOT NULL,
   created_date timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
   is_sent BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
   email_template VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: It seems a `jave.util.UUID` [parameter is mapped](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAnorm#Parameters) to a String of length 17 for JDBC.

Comment: Yes, there is a conversion in anorm.ToStatement. However, even I `import anorm.ToStatement.uuidToStatement` I still receive the same error

Comment: If you look at the [source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.9/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/anorm/ToStatement.scala#L406-419) of `uuidToStatement`, the `UUID` value is just set as a `String` value on the underlying `java.sql.PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Use `{id}::uuid` in the statement, so that the `java.util.UUID` passed as `String` in JDBC parameters is then converted from passed `VARCHAR` to a specific PostgreSQL `uuid`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anorm is DB agnostic, as JDBC, so vendor specific datatype are not supported by default.

You can use `{id}::uuid` in the statement, so that the `java.util.UUID` passed as String in JDBC parameters is then converted from passed `VARCHAR` to a specific PostgreSQL `uuid`.

> Using string interpolation in `SQL(s"...")` is not recommanded (SQL injection), but Anorm interpolation can be used.

```
def insert(email:EmailQueue): Unit = DB.withTransaction { implicit c =>
  SQL"""
    INSERT INTO "email_queue" ( "body", "created_date", "id", "is_sent", "send_from", "send_to", "subject", "email_template")
    VALUES ( ${email.body}, ${email.created_date}, ${email.id}::uuid, ${email.is_sent}, ${email.send_from}, ${email.send_to}, ${email.subject}, ${email.email_template} )
  """).executeInsert()
}
```

> Not recommended, but can be useful sometimes for vendor specific type, the `anorm.Object` can be used to pass an opaque value as JDBC parameter (there the `::uuid` is nicer for me).
>
> You can also implement a custom `ToStatement[java.util.UUID]`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and the solution. Your solution works well for me. Only one small change is that instead of calling `executeInsert()` I called `executeUpdate` otherwise I receive error that cannot convert UUID to Long. `Error: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 87adfc2f-9985-42e1-a501-d36b9d9f83b6: class java.util.UUID to Long for column ColumnName(email_queue.id,Some(id)))]]`  I'm not sure why it has this problem

Comment: The error is because your table seems to have return the UUID as JDBC generated key, and `.executeInsert` try to handle such key, but by default as auto-incremented numeric (`Long`). Fortunatly, you can use a custom parser also for such key returned on insertion: `.executeInsert(anorm.SqlParser.scalar[java.util.UUID].singleOpt)`.