# Insert NULL into nullable column with custom ToStatement in Anorm 2.4

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

In our project we have a custom mapping to one of our classes (`Muid`) as follows:

```
implicit val muidToStatement: ToStatement[Muid] = new ToStatement[Muid] {
        def set(s: PreparedStatement, index: Int, muid: Muid): Unit = s.setObject(index, muid.uuid)
    }
```

ParameterMetaData implementation:

```
implicit object MuidClassMetaData extends ParameterMetaData[Muid] {
        val sqlType = ParameterMetaData.StringParameterMetaData.sqlType
        val jdbcType = ParameterMetaData.StringParameterMetaData.jdbcType
    }
```

In number of places we need to set `null` to Optional columns, such as:

```
SQL(sql).on(
    'id -> id,
    'created_by_id -> createdById,
    'organization_id -> organizationId,
    'parent_folder_id -> optionalParentFolderId, // <= Optional and nullable column
    'name -> name
)
```

This used to work on Anorm 2.3, What I am getting now though is:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "parent_folder_id" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I suspect that the mapping must be fixed, however, I didn't find much docs about custom mapping for optional values.

Also, it looks like it have something to do with Optional `java.util.UUID` mapping, since I am getting the same type of error in every case where I have `Muid` (Which is a simple wrapper for UUID)

What is the correct way to solve that?

The only way I could solve the problem without modifying ALL the queries is by adding `?stringtype=unspecified` to JDBC connection URL. But, That feels not right.

Thanks,

P.S. I am extremely new to Play & Anorm, Sorry.

Comment: Are you saying that `optionalParentFolderId` has type `Option[Muid]`?

Comment: In this specific scenario it is passed as None

Comment: As suggested in the doc, it's recommended to pass `Option.empty[T]` instead of `None`. Then you also need to be sure you've properly implemented the `ParameterMetaData`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert value of UUID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30985604/how-to-insert-value-of-uuid)

Comment: So, passing Option.empty does not change anything. I thing the main problem is the second part. I added ParameterMetaData implementation

Comment: As for the "interpolation", it seem to be working. in some sort of way. Not sure what is this mechanism doing though. Do I need to update ALL the queries in the entire application now?

Comment: I just realized that the ParameterMetaData in my code is set to StringParameterMetaData. However, even if I switch to UUIDParameterMetaData, it is actually the same thing. What is the correct JDBC mapping for UUID?

Comment: Please have a look at the link to the other question about passing UUID as string.

Comment: I did, and it seem to work, but does it mean that I now need to update the queries in the entire application? How did it work before ?

Comment: Just have a look at the doc